# ternary operator in a function

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I'm new to ternary operators. I have the following function. I'm trying to understand what's going on:

```
function toProperHex(hex) {
    hex = hex.toLowerCase();
    return hex ? hex != 'ffffff' ? '#' + hex : '#eee' : '#000';
}
```

I know that whatever is before the ? is the condition and what comes after is the value that the variable becomes if the condition is true, and after the colon, will be what the cariable becomes if the condition is not true. Now there are two conditions apparently and three possible outcomes. Is this an if / else if statement with a Ternary structure. Clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is two ternary operators on one line. It's equivalent to this:

```
if(hex) {
    if(hex != 'ffffff') {
        return '#' + hex;
    } else {
        return '#eee';
    }
} else {
    return '#000';
}
```

I think two ternaries on one line is a bad idea, makes them hard to read. You can basically divide it up like this

```
return hex ? (hex != 'ffffff' ? '#' + hex : '#eee') : '#000';
```

The parentheses help show the inner ternary.

Comment: Thanks! Makes more sense now. Now the question is, I know that Hex is going to be a String. either empty or with some values. What would you be evaluating in the first if(hex). Don't know if you need more context to clarify that.

Comment: The first line is checking whether hex has a value or not. If it's actually `null`, `undefined` or the empty string `''`, then that if statement will fail and it will bounce down into the last else.